# Matlab function and return values in a loop

Tags: matlab

If I define a function like this

```
function [x, y] = findXY(B)
   [by, bx] = size(B);
   x = zeros(by,bx);
   y = zeros(by,bx);
   for i=1:10
       x(i) = i;
       y(i) = i; 
   end
end
```

I get the following error

> The constructor for class 'findXY' must return only one output value.

Why is this happening? I can't use return values in a loop?
I didn't find something similar while googling.

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? How are you calling this function and how is it defined? Seems to work fine for me on R2009b when this function is alone in an m-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question. The problem was a bit weird. I just restarted matlab and everything worked as expected. So if you walk into trouble and you cant find what is going wrong you should give restarting a try. It may work.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it:

```
[x, y] = findXY(ones(10,10))
```

and there is no problem. Could you give a more detailed explanation about where and how are you using it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the function is considered as constructor of a class - does it maybe sit in a directory named `@TestXY`?

And in this case, you are only allowed to return one object.

Maybe you could wrap your two return values into one cell array...

Something like

```
function xy = findXY(B)
   [by, bx] = size(B);
   x = zeros(by,bx);
   y = zeros(by,bx);
   for i=1:10
       x(i) = i;
       y(i) = i; 
   end
   xy = {x y};
end
```

But if the function is not a constructor, your code is perfectly valid.

Comment: The directory name is "matlab". Does this make a difference? I can't return a single value cause I am rewriting a function that has this output and changing it will affect a lot of code.